# No connection with local network after VPN connection established

Tags: networking, vpn

If got 4 servers. 2 servers on location BOZ en 2 servers on location RSD. These locations both have connection to another network.

Each location has 1 server called VPN-"location" and 1 server DC-"location".

When there is no VPN established between VPN-RSD and VPN-BOZ, VPN-BOZ and DC-BOZ can ping each other on hostname and IP-adres. On the moment I establish a VPN connection, VPN-BOZ loses all connectivity to the local network and with DC-BOZ. Though I'm able to connect to remote resources on the RSD-network.

VPN-BOZ and VPN-RSD both have 2 NIC's. One NIC is connected to the local network and the other one is connected to the external network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Check the two location are not using the same IP address range. If yes, IP configuration on one of your location will have to be changed.

(2) In your vpn connection settings

1. Goto **Networking**
2. Select **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)**
3. Click **Properties**
4. Click **Advanced**
5. Remove check mark **Use default gateway on remote network**